# Specifying input and output ranges to algorithms

Tags: c++, c++11

There are a number of use cases in the standard library, and I have run into my own code, situations where I want to pass an input and an output range that must be the same size, often to some algorithm. At present this requires three, or four if you want to be careful, iterators. Often there is then a bunch of checking to make sure the iterators make sense.

I am aware that array_view might, in some cases, coalesce pairs of being/end iterators but that still leaves checks required that the input and output array_views might be different size. Has there been any discussion on a class to contain both the input and the output range specifications? Maybe the range proposal solves some or all of this of this but I'm not clear how it does.

Comment: Can you include a brief example of your use-case?

Answer (score 0):

I often have a similar use case. I have found that the most versatile method is to pass a reference to an output 'container' concept rather than a range or pair of iterators. Then the algorithm is free to resize or extend the container as necessary and the possibility of buffer overruns disappears.

for (a simple contrived) example, something like:

```
template<class InputIter, class OutputContainer>
void encrypt_to(OutputContainer& dest, InputIter first, InputIter last)
{
  dest.resize(last - first);
  // ... todo: replace this with some actual encryption
  std::copy(first, last, dest.begin());
}
```

For functions where I want to hide the implementation, I have an abstract interface representing the destination container. It needs virtual `begin()`, `end()` and `resize()` methods.

for example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

struct mutable_byte_buffer_concept {
    using iterator=uint8_t*;
    virtual iterator begin() = 0;
    virtual iterator end() = 0;
    virtual void resize(size_t newsize) = 0;

    // note : no virtual destructor - by design.
};

template<class Container>
struct mutable_byte_buffer_model : mutable_byte_buffer_concept
{
    mutable_byte_buffer_model(Container& container)
    : container(container)
    {
    }

    virtual iterator begin()  override
    {
        return reinterpret_cast<iterator>(&container[0]);
    }

    virtual iterator end()  override
    {
        return reinterpret_cast<iterator>(&container[0]) + container.size();
    }

    virtual void resize(size_t newsize)  override
    {
        container.resize(newsize);
    }

    Container& container;
};

template<class Container>
auto make_mutable_buffer(Container& c)
-> mutable_byte_buffer_model<Container>
{
    return { c };
}

// note: accepting an rvalue allows me to use polymorphism at the call site without needing any memory allocation
template<class Iter>
void copy_to(mutable_byte_buffer_concept&& dest, Iter first, Iter last)
{
    dest.resize(last - first);
    std::copy(first, last, dest.begin());
}

using namespace std;

auto main() -> int
{
    auto a = "Hello, World"s;
    string b;
    vector<uint8_t> c;
    string d;
    copy_to(make_mutable_buffer(b), begin(a), end(a));
    copy_to(make_mutable_buffer(c), begin(b), end(b));
    copy_to(make_mutable_buffer(d), begin(c), end(c));
    cout << d << endl;
    return 0;
}
```